# ng-options value is wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Select value is being generated wrong

```
$scope.statuses     = [
       {"key": "open", "value": "Open"},
       {"key": "work in progress", "value": "Work in Progress"},
       {"key": "dismiss", "value": "Dismiss"},
       {"key": "not an issue", "value": "Not an Issue"},
       {"key": "close", "value": "Close"}
];    



<select ng-options="status.key as status.value for status in statuses"
                        ng-model="complaint.status">
</select>
```

*Generated HTML*

```
<select ng-options="status.key as status.value for status in statuses" ng-model="complaint.status" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Open">Open</option>
    <option value="1" label="Work in Progress">Work in Progress</option>
    <option value="2" label="Dismiss">Dismiss</option>
    <option value="3" label="Not an Issue">Not an Issue</option>
    <option value="4" label="Close">Close</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17886/

Comment: looks like html value has no correlation with angular value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the generated html doesn't show the actual 'key' in your $scope.statuses array, it's the correct way. Angular saves a reference to the actual value and handles the rest.
You can prove it by checking KG Christensen fiddle, specially this line where he prints the actual model value:

```
<h2>Val: {{complaint.status}}</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17886/

More info: [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an initial value for the ngModel i.e.

```
$scope.complaint = { status : "open" };
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/zwq99seo/)